# How to create two columns from two different subqueries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two different queries from a single table and I want to merge these queries into a different column

First query:

```
select user_id,meta_value as fee 
FROM magni_usermeta 
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'clinic_%_fee' 
ORDER BY user_id DESC
```

result:

```
  user_id        fee      
*********************
    7          500
    5          450
    5          344
    4          500
    4          700
    2          210
    2          200
```

second query:

```
select user_id,meta_value as clinic 
FROM magni_usermeta 
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'clinic_%_clinic_name' 
ORDER BY user_id DESC
```

result:

```
     user_id      clinic
    *********************
        7          99
        5          90
        5          99
        4          99
        4          92
        2          91
        2          90
```

I want a query which will give something like this:

```
   user_id        fee           clinic
    **********************************
        7          500             99
        5          450             90
        5          344             99
        4          500             99
        4          700             92
        2          210             91
        2          200             90
```

I have tried this but do not get the exact result I want:

```
select user_id,meta_value as clinic 
FROM magni_usermeta 
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'clinic_%_clinic_name' 
UNION select user_id,meta_value as fee 
FROM magni_usermeta 
WHERE meta_key LIKE 'clinic_%_fee' 
ORDER BY user_id DESC
```

Comment: Are there any other columns to help map between the two result sets? For user 5, how do you know the 450 fee applies to clinic 90 and not 99?

Comment: for meta key clinic_0_clinic_name meta value is 90
for meta key clinic_0_fee meta value is 450

for meta key clinic_1_clinic_name meta value is 344
for meta key clinic_1_fee meta value is 99

Comment: For join the two query we need  more columns for relation   .. with the sample you provided .. the join product more rows for repeated  value in user_id

Comment: these two queries are from same table user_meta

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by

```
select
  A.user_id,
  group_concat( case when A.tableName = 'fee' then A.meta_value end) as fee,
  group_concat( case when A.tableName = 'clinic' then A.meta_value end) as clinic
from (
  select user_id,meta_value as meta_value, 'fee' as tableName FROM magni_usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'clinic_%_fee' 

  union

  select user_id,meta_value as meta_value, 'clinic' as tableName FROM magni_usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'clinic_%_clinic_name' 

) as A
group by A.user_id
```

Comment: @SoubhagyaKumar, It's fixed. Please check.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'table FROM magni_usermeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'clinic_%_fee'

Comment: table is a predefined keyword so we can't use that i have change the name also but not working

Answer (score 0):

We need to join to itself to get the clinic name:

```
SELECT um.user_id, um.meta_value AS fee, um2.meta_value AS clinic 
FROM magni_usermeta um 
JOIN magni_usermeta um2 ON um2.meta_key = REPLACE(um.meta_key, '_fee', '_clinic_name') 
WHERE um.meta_key LIKE 'clinics_%_fee' 
ORDER BY um.user_id DESC
```

Comment: what is the um.clinic ( Unknown column 'um.clinic' in 'field list')

Comment: if i remove um.clinic then some results appearing twice

Comment: I'm attempting to extract the clinic number from the meta fields and match on that since it is not available as an independent field. Does that work?

Comment: returned an empty result set

Comment: Try that simplified query

Comment: its working but in the clinic column getting 'clinic_'   in all rows

you didn't wrote anything for clinic column but the fee column hwing perfect

Comment: now it's showing clinics_0 clinics_1 in clinic column i want result like 90,91 in clinic column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162025/discussion-between-sorak-and-soubhagya-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.meta_value as fee, b.meta_value as clinic
FROM magni_usermeta a
JOIN magni_usermeta b
ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE a.meta_key LIKE  'clinic_%_fee'
  AND b.meta_key LIKE 'clinic_%_clinic_name'
ORDER BY a.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `inner join`

```
select a.user_id,a.meta_value as clinic, fee FROM magni_usermeta a Inner Join
 magni_usermeta b
 on a.user_id = b.user_id
 WHERE meta_key LIKE 'clinic_%_clinic_name' 
 ORDER BY user_id DESC
```

Comment: Unknown column 'fee' in 'field list'

Comment: fee is not a column

Comment: There is no such column as meta_key in your db is it? or if you are associating meta_key with some column then use alias properly

Answer (score 0):

You can try inner join on same tables. I have a example for postmetas. In example `_wp_attachment_metadata` and `_wp_attached_file` are my `meta_key` values.

```
SELECT
  m1.post_id as 'POST ID',
  m1.meta_id as 'META ID',
  m1.meta_value AS 'meta1', 
  m2.meta_value AS 'meta2'

FROM wp_postmeta m1

INNER JOIN 
  wp_postmeta m2
  ON m1.post_id = m2.post_id

WHERE 
  m1.meta_key = '_wp_attachment_metadata'
    AND
  m2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
try this;
select a.user_id,(select b.meta_value FROM magni_usermeta b WHERE b.meta_key LIKE 'clinic_%_fee' AND b.user_id=a.user_id) as fee,(select c.meta_value FROM magni_usermeta c WHERE c.meta_key LIKE 'clinic_%_clinic_name' AND c.user_id=a.user_id) as clinic from magni_usermeta a GROUP BY a.user_id ORDER BY a.user_id DESC
```

Comment: null as a result

Comment: Subquery returns more than 1 row